# redirect wordpress to another url detected browser language

Tags: wordpress, redirect, browser, detection, lang

I have a htaccess file with wordpress basic configuration like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This wordpress is in spanish.
I have another wordpress in english in another domain "domain2.com"
I need to add a redirect to "domain2.com" when the browser detects user lang.
If browser lang is "es", nothing extra to do. If browser lang is "en", redirect to another url and finish. 
How can I do it?

Comment: r u using wpml for language translation

Comment: i don't want to translate the spanish wordpress to english, the english wordpress is totally independent from the spanish wordpress. I only need to detect the lang and make a redirection to another site.